# Deleting non-contiguous cell ranges ( Run-time error 1004 )

Tags: vba, excel, range, runtime-error

I want to delete the contents of a range of cells “D8:I13” , then the same range , but 15 rows lower , then another 15 rows below and so 55 times .
I wrote the code but the error pops up : Run-time error 1004 ( Method ‘Range’ of object’_Global’ failed )

```
    Sub удалитьссылки()
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx")
    A = "8+n*15"
    B = "13+n*15"

    'переходим в активную страницу откуда надо скопировать данные
    book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Activate

    n = 0
    Do Until n = 55

    Range("D" + A + ":I" + B + "").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    n = n + 1
    Loop


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find using `Cells` easier:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long
    Dim LoopNum As Long

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\?????? ??????\???????\??????.xlsx")

    With book1.Worksheets("????1")
        Do Until LoopNum = 55
            'Cells uses row number & column number.
            '.Range(StartCell, EndCell) creates a range between the two cells.
            .Range(.Cells(8 + (LoopNum * 15), 4), .Cells(13 + (LoopNum * 15), 9)).ClearContents
            LoopNum = LoopNum + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Fix the crylic characters :)

Comment: I knew someone would comment on that, so I googled and searched SO.  Maybe I should start a new question - how do you fix crylic characters on a computer that's locked down tighter than a, um, very tight thing.

Answer (score 0):

Code will not work unless you change some placements and do some edits.

```
Sub удалитьссылки()
'privet!
        Dim book1 As Workbook
        Dim A,B,n As Long


        Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx") _
       'Or anything like ActiveWorkbook

        'переходим в активную страницу откуда надо скопировать данные

        n = 0
        Do Until n = 55

        A = 8 + (n * 15)
        B = 13 + (n * 15)

        book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("D" & A & ":I" & B).ClearContents

        n = n + 1
        Loop


    End Sub
```

First of all when you Define variables as *A* and *B* on your example, if you put them between  quotation marks like A= " 8+n*15 " then this will become a String not a number. You should change it to `A = 8 + n * 15` And you should move it after Do loop otherwise you will only be able to clear first range.

Then ("D" + A + ":I" + B + "") is also completely wrong. You should use *&* sign to separate your variables with actual ranges. If you would like to add some values to your variable, than you may use *+* sign.  (For example `("D" & A + 1 & ":I" & B - 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, there's no need to use `Activate` the sheet before clearing it's contents, instead just use fully qualifed `Range` syntax like : `book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("D" & A & ":I" & B).ClearContents`.

Explanation inside the code as comments.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub удалитьссылки()

Dim book1       As Workbook
Dim n           As Long
Dim A           As Long ' <-- need to be numeric type, not String
Dim B           As Long ' <-- need to be numeric type, not String

Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx")

For n = 1 To 55 ' <-- use a simple For loop instead of Do until
    A = 8 + 15 * (n - 1) ' <-- substract 1 since the first range start from row 8
    B = 13 + 15 * (n - 1)  ' <-- substract 1 since the first range start from row 13

    book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("D" & A & ":I" & B).ClearContents
Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can see a few errors here:

- your coding doesn't know what `n` is. It hasn't been defined
- `A` and `B` are not strings, they are numbers.
- Your formulas for `A` and `B` are outside your loop. And as such don't increase as `n` does

Try the following code:

```
Sub удалитьссылки()
Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim A,B,n as Long

Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx")

'переходим в активную страницу откуда надо скопировать данные
book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Activate

n = 0
Do Until n = 55
    A = 8+(n*15)
    B = 13+(n*15)

    Range("D" & A & ":I" & B).ClearContents
    n = n + 1
Loop


End Sub
```